# Error when creating Shopify dynamic sections

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I am creating a new Shopify dynamic section but I get an error message which prevents me from saving it. It may be a syntax error but there is no way of knowing when in shopify, as the error message is very general. Any help welcome.

```
<section>
  <p>{{ section.settings.customTitle}} </p>
</section>


{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "gallery",
    "settings": [
        {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "customTitle",
        "label": "Custom Title",
        "default": "This is a title"
        }
    ],
    "presets": [
      {
        "name": "gallery",
        "category": "galleries"
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: What is the error? There is no issue with the provided code. The only issue may be if you are editing an existing section that had content entered before it, which might throw an error. Check it by creating a different section file ( with different file name and preset )

Comment: You were right, there was still content in the CMS, which was preventing me saving the file.